# Encrypt with a specific key and uncrypt with another specific key

Tags: encryption, encoding, cryptography

There are some encrypt method that allow I encrypt a string data with a specific unique encode key (*write key*) and decode it to an another specific decode key (*read key*)?

For instance: supposing that we have the string `Hello World`. So we have two keys, one for encoding (like `John`) and another to decoding (like `Doe`). So we create an encoded version of string like:

***Note**: not limited to PHP, it just an easy example for me...*

```
$string = "Hello World";
$encoded = encode($string, "John", "Doe");
//@function encode(string data, string write_key, string read_key);
//@return string "abcdef123456" -- supposing that it is the encoded string!
```

Now we have the new encoded string of `Hello World` data as `abcdef123456`. Now if we try to read this string with the *write key* we don't will get the original version, but a strange version or just an error like `invalid read key`.

```
$decoded = decode($encoded, "John");
//@function decode(string data, string read_key);
//@return false -- invalid read key! or just a strange result data

$decoded = decode($encoded, "Doe");
//@return string "Hello World"
```

*Note:* I just need to know if there are some encrypt project like that, but if you know a library, it's ok too. I need it to my project. I know that is possible hash with a key, but the original result never can back. And I know too *read-write key* encodings, but it doesn't is really what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about [Public key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography#Public-key_cryptography).

To suggest a library you should specify the language you will be using in your project.

Comment: It's perfectly what I'm searching for! Thanks. About the language, it's optional on topic, but I think some to PHP and/or JS.

Comment: Here is the documentation for PHP Cryptography: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.crypto.php